# Inserting 1D vector into 2D vector Without Creating Temp 1D Vector

Tags: c++, stdvector

This is my code.

```cpp
vector<vector<string>> table;
vector<string> record;

// .....
record.push_back("Apple");
record.push_back("Orange");

table.push_back(record);

// ....
```

Here to insert a row in a 2D vector I'm creating a new 1D vector called record. My Question is, "Is there any way to insert a those data into 2D vector without Creating 1D vector ??"

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways. The first way is to make table a vector of pointers to vector instead of a vector of vectors.
ie:

```
vector<vector<string>*> table
```

.. and then stack pointers to the records instead of records themselves, which is very small.
the other way is if you know you won't be using your 1D vector anymore, you can move it to the table vector
ie :

```
table.push_back(std::move(record));
```

Just know that, from then on with that way of doing it, that specific record object will be in an undefined state, ie unusable, except from within your table.

Comment: vector pointers. however pointers to vector objects is more clear for newer people

Comment: I took the second way. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this:

```
v.emplace_back( std::initializer_list<std::string> {"Apple", "Orange"} );
```

`emplace_back` forwards its arguments to construct a vector in place. See a [reference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back).

Comment: does `v.emplace_back({"Apple", "Orange"});` not work?

Answer (score 0):

This method is not thread-safe, but if you have just one thread you may get good performance:

```
vector<vector<string> > table;

// insert empty element
table.push_back(vector<string>());

// get reference to last inserted element
vector<string>& record = table.back();
record.push_back("Apple");
record.push_back("Orange");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GCC, then you can use "Initializer lists" (C++11 feature) like this:

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> > myvector;
myvector[0] = {10,20,30};
```

However Visual Studio compiler still does not support this C++11 feature.